# How I can sort a ListView about a LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sorting, linkbutton

I use a ListView in my ASP.Net Application with the Columns

`[Lastname] [Firstname] [telephonenumber][Department][eMail]` and

My ListView built in LayoutTemplate, ItemTemplate and AlternatingItemTemplate.

Now I want that if I **click** on The Headertext Lastname or Firstname that I get a sortlist.
How I can do this?

Here is my ListView:

```
   <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView" OnItemCommand="myListView_ItemCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanging="myListView_SelectedIndexChanging">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE" class="TableClass">
                <th align="left" id="th4" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Nachname" ID="lnkNachname" runat="server" >id_Nachname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                <th align="left" id="th3" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Vorname" ID="lnkVorname" runat="server" >id_Vorname</asp:LinkButton></th>
                <th align="left" id="th5" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="lnkTelefon" runat="server" >id_Telefon</asp:Label></th>
                <th align="left" id="th6" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="lnkAbteilung" runat="server">id_Abteilung</asp:Label></th>
                <th align="left" id="th2" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="lnkemail" runat="server" >id_Email</asp:Label></th> 
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr class="TableClass"> 
             <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
             <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
             <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
             <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label7" Text='<%# Eval("Abteilung") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
             <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>


          <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <AlternatingItemTemplate>

        <tr class="TableClass"> 
            <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefonnummer") %>' runat="server" /></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label7" Text='<%# Eval("Abteilung") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
            <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton CssClass="MyLink" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>

            <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label6" Text='<%# Eval("GUID") %>' runat="server" Visible="False" /></td>

        </tr>

    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

cs code:

```
protected void myListView_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SortExpression == "Vorname")
        {
            e.SortDirection = System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            e.SortDirection = System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to get the event, when the header is clicked. And then get all items in your listview, sort them (either by string or int or by an own sort-algorithm) and then add the new sorted list to your listview

Comment: look at my update...how is wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html code is

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstLogs" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="tr">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="hdrRowColor1">
                                    <td align="left" width="20px" style="display: none;">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="selectall" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /><%--onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked);"--%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="35px">
                                        S.No
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="120px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkName" runat="server" CommandArgument="FirstName" ValidationGroup="vgSearch"
                                            OnClick="lnk_Sort">Name</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkName" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="120px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEmail" runat="server" CommandArgument="u.EmailAddress" ValidationGroup="vgSearch"
                                            OnClick="lnk_Sort">Email</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkEmail" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="60px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRole" runat="server" CommandArgument="RoleName" ValidationGroup="vgSearch"
                                            OnClick="lnk_Sort">Role</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkRole" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="160px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" CommandArgument="Page" ValidationGroup="vgSearch"
                                            OnClick="lnk_Sort">Page Name</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkPage" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="105px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkMac" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblUserActivities.MacAddress"
                                            ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">MAC Address</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkMac" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="70px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkIp" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblUserActivities.IpAddress"
                                            ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">I.P Address</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkIp" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="60px">
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCreatedDate" runat="server" CommandArgument="tblUserActivities.CreatedDate"
                                            ValidationGroup="vgSearch" OnClick="lnk_Sort">Created Date</asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:Image ID="img_lnkCreatedDate" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr id="tr" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr class='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Container.DataItemIndex % 2) ? "EvenRowColor" : "OddRowColor" %>'>
                                <%--<td align="left">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItem" runat="server" CssClass="case" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblpKId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pkActivityId") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </td>--%>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%# Eval("RowNum")%>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblUserId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserId")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") + " " + Eval("LastName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%--<asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%# GetUserRole(Eval("RoleName"), Eval("DesignationName"))%>'></asp:Label>--%>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRole" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoleName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Page")).Replace("~/","")%>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%# Eval("MacAddress")%>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%# Eval("IpAddress")%>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("CreatedDate")).ToString("MMM, dd yyyy")%>

                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

code behind code is

```
 protected void lnk_Sort(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    string arg = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
    ViewState["sortCol"] = arg;
    GetSortDirection();
    BindData(ViewState["sortCol"].ToString(), ViewState["sortDir"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["nmbr"]), Pager.PageSize);
    string name = lnk.ID;
    Image img = (Image)(lstLogs.FindControl("img_" + name));
    if (img != null)
    {
        SetSortOrderImage(img, ViewState["sortDir"].ToString());
    }
}
private void SetSortOrderImage(Image image, String sortorder)
{
    if (sortorder == "asc")
    {
        image.Visible = true;
        image.ImageUrl = "../App_Themes/ThemeNew2/images/up.png";
    }
    else if (sortorder == "Desc")
    {
        image.Visible = true;
        image.ImageUrl = "../App_Themes/ThemeNew2/images/down.png";

    }
}
 private void GetSortDirection()
{
    if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortDir"]) == "Desc")
    {
        ViewState["sortDir"] = "asc";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["sortDir"] = "Desc";
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: @Tarasov Please review i have added.. sorry i missed that

Comment: it is the right way but it doesn't work with my Application :( I don't use images first and I f I click on the sort link I get a empty list back ...now is my question what I forget to fill the ListView with the sort data :/ ...but thanks for your help :P